# Angular2 получить доступ к изображению вне проекта

Tags: изображения, angular2

Сервер сайта(интернет-магазин) написан на java, и я решил хранить изображения продуктов в виде файлов на сервере. И столкнулся с тем, что я не знаю куда именно их сохранить, чтобы из ангуляра получить  доступ к ним. Хранить их все в папке assets в проекте с ангуляром - нормальная практика? Если хранить их в другом месте (скажем, на другом Томе диска), то как получить к ним доступ(буду признателен за пример кода)?